# How to scale ImageView after the orientation is changed?

Tags: android, imageview, orientation, screen-rotation

When I rotate the screen, ImageView doesn't rescale image, but native Imageview rotates the image.
How can I achieve this?

Project https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="ScaleTypeCenterInsidePortrait"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
```

My ScaleTypeCenterInsidePortrait class:

```
public class ScaleTypeCenterInsidePortrait extends ExampleActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scale_type_inside_portrait);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is clearly written that it does not supports rotation.

Comment: yes, I override onConfigurationChanged, but what method recalculate image scale and redraw layout.

Answer (score 1):

replace these lines in your code

```
public class ScaleTypeCenterInsidePortrait extends ExampleActivity {

ImageView imv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
imv=new ImageView(this);
imv.setimageResource(R.drawable."your image name in the drwable folder");
imv.setscaleType(ScaleType.Center_Inside);

    }
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            setContentView(imv);
        }
        else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(imv);         
        }
    }
```

}
and put you manifest these line

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_name"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

Comment: ImageView work fine, but I use GestureImageView (1st post) - it does not work

Comment: Try this and let me inform,                                       GestureImageview giv=GestureImageview)findviewById(R.id."yourGestureImageviewId"); giv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);//default scaleType

Comment: it works, but layout after orientation changes not rescale for actual device screen

Comment: it works means put upvote for my answer dude  and check u added these lines in your XML                                      gesture-image:min-scale="0.1" 
gesture-image:max-scale="10.0" 
gesture-image:strict="false"

Comment: that's not what I needed

Comment: i open activity - it show image, then i rotate my device with android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" and   activity does not recalculate the scale of the image, it simply turns... how to recalculate in onConfigurationChanged?

Comment: check this link they used the webview scaling for onscreen changes you replace that your gestureimageview object instead of webview k         http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/

Comment: have you look at that link dude

Comment: I tried your example, but the result is the same - the image is not scaled